# Will Allah hold me accountable?

Tags: quran, sunnah, halal-haram, evil-thoughts

If we said something bad about Allah but you really didnt say it,you just said it in your throat with no voice and no lips moving just your throat moving, will Allah hold us accountable?

Answer (score 0):

If you meant it, then I believe so because that would mean the intent was to spite Allah. All I can say is to repent and be careful to never do it again.